# Adding index to pd.Series gives Nan

Tags: pandas, series

Trying to get through the httlads course in runestone.academy, no idea what's going wrong. The objective is to "Create a Series object called `budget_lookup` such that you are able to use a call to `budget_lookup['Dead Presidents']` to find the budget of that movie."

This after filtering the original dataset to movies with budgets of >1M as below. So far this is what I have.

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Downloads/movies_metadata.csv').dropna(axis=1, how='all')

budget_df = df[df.budget > 1000000]

budget_lookup = pd.Series(budget_df.budget,
                          index=budget_df.title).iloc

print(budget_lookup.head)
```

Which gives me the following:

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of title
Toy Story                          NaN
Jumanji                            NaN
Waiting to Exhale                  NaN
Heat                               NaN
Sabrina                            NaN
                                    ..
Thick Lashes of Lauri Mäntyvaara   NaN
Corporate Event                    NaN
Mars                               NaN
Pro Lyuboff                        NaN
Antidur                            NaN
Name: budget, Length: 7208, dtype: float64>
```

First five lines of the dataset:

```
    belongs_to_collection   budget  genres  homepage    id  imdb_id original_language   original_title  overview    popularity  ... release_date    revenue runtime spoken_languages    status  tagline title   video   vote_average    vote_count
0   {'id': 10194, 'name': 'Toy Story Collection', ...   30000000    [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, '...   http://toystory.disney.com/toy-story    862.0   tt0114709   en  Toy Story   Led by Woody, Andy's toys live happily in his ...   21.946943   ... 1995-10-30  373554033.0 81.0    [{'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}]    Released    NaN Toy Story   False   7.7 5415.0
1   NaN 65000000    [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, '...   NaN 8844.0  tt0113497   en  Jumanji When siblings Judy and Peter discover an encha...   17.015539   ... 1995-12-15  262797249.0 104.0   [{'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}, {'iso...   Released    Roll the dice and unleash the excitement!   Jumanji False   6.9 2413.0
3   NaN 16000000    [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'nam...   NaN 31357.0 tt0114885   en  Waiting to Exhale   Cheated on, mistreated and stepped on, the wom...   3.859495    ... 1995-12-22  81452156.0  127.0   [{'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}]    Released    Friends are the people who let you be yourself...   Waiting to Exhale   False   6.1 34.0
5   NaN 60000000    [{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'nam...   NaN 949.0   tt0113277   en  Heat    Obsessive master thief, Neil McCauley leads a ...   17.924927   ... 1995-12-15  187436818.0 170.0   [{'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}, {'iso...   Released    A Los Angeles Crime Saga    Heat    False   7.7 1886.0
6   NaN 58000000    [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10749, '...   NaN 11860.0 tt0114319   en  Sabrina An ugly duckling having undergone a remarkable...   6.677277    ... 1995-12-15  0.0 127.0   [{'iso_639_1': 'fr', 'name': 'Français'}, {'is...   Released    You are cordially invited to the most surprisi...   Sabrina False   6.2 141.0
```

Comment: what is iloc for ? and should it be head()?

Comment: as @YOandBEN_W said, change `budget_lookup = pd.Series(budget_df.budget,
                          index=budget_df.title).iloc` to `budget_lookup = pd.Series(budget_df.budget,
                          index=budget_df.title)` and change `print(budget_lookup.head)` to `print(budget_lookup.head())`

Comment: @Datanovice tried that`budget_lookup = pd.Series(budget_df.budget, index=budget_df.title)` `print(budget_lookup.head())` And still got this...`title
Toy Story           NaN(...)
Name: budget, dtype: float64`

Comment: @AndréSoares I'm struggling with this question too, have you figured out the solution? Would you mind sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Using values will convert column 'Budget' to array:

```
budget_lookup = pd.Series(budget_df.budget.values, index=budget_df.title)
```